# Powershell and XML file creation

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

This is the first time I've ever tried to create an XML file. I am trying to write a script that queries our list of GPOs and generates an XML file that has the name of the name of the GPO and the servers to which the apply.

I am running into two issues:

- The XML file is created with the first GPO, but I get all of the servers in "NodeName" tag, instead of many.

> < MasterList >
>       < Tag >
>       < TagName >WSUS-ALPHA < /TagName >
>       < NodeName >SERVER1 SERVER2 SERVER3 SERVER4 < /NodeName >
>       < /Tag >
>       < /MasterList >

- After the first GPO is written to the XML file, I get the following errors for the rest:

> Exception calling "WriteStartElement" with "1" argument(s): "The Writer is closed."
>   At line:3 char:5
>   + $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('Tag')
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
>
> Exception calling "WriteElementString" with "2" argument(s): "Token StartElement in state Error would result in an
>   invalid XML document."
>   At line:4 char:5
>   +     $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('TagName',$gpo.DisplayName)
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
>
> Exception calling "WriteElementString" with "2" argument(s): "Token StartElement in state Error would result in an
>   invalid XML document."
>   At line:10 char:13
>   +             $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('NodeName',(Get-ADGroupMember -Identit ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
>
> Exception calling "WriteEndElement" with "0" argument(s): "There was no XML start tag open."
>   At line:13 char:5
>   +     $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
>
> Exception calling "WriteEndElement" with "0" argument(s): "There was no XML start tag open."
>   At line:14 char:5
>   +     $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
>
> Exception calling "Flush" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot write to a closed TextWriter."
>   At line:15 char:5
>   +     $xmlWriter.Flush()
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ObjectDisposedException

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$xmlFile = "c:\data-$randomnumber.xml"
$xmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter($xmlFile,$Null)
$xmlWriter.Formatting = 'Indented'
$xmlWriter.Indentation = 1
$xmlWriter.IndentChar = "`t"
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('MasterList')

#Get the list of GPOs that start with "wsus".
$wsusGPOs = Get-GPO -All | where {$_.DisplayName -like 'wsus*'} 

Foreach ($gpo in $wsusGPOs) {
    #For each GPO that starts with "wsus", create a tag with the GPO's name.
    $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('Tag')
    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('TagName',$gpo.DisplayName)

    #Get the list of AD groups that have the "Apply" permission, in each GPO.
    $wsusPerms = $gpo | Get-GPPermission -All | where {$_.permission -eq 'GpoApply' -and $_.denied -eq $false}
    Foreach ($permsList in $wsusPerms) {
        If ($permsList.trustee.name -ne 'Authenticated Users') {
            #For each AD group that can apply the GPO, get the list of servers in the AD group. Ignores the "Authenticated Users" group. 
            $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('NodeName',(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $permsList.Trustee.name -Recursive).name)
        }
    }

    $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
    $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
    $xmlWriter.Flush()
    $xmlWriter.Close()

    }
```

I tried moving the $xmlWriter.Flush() and $xmlWriter.Close() commands out of the top foreach loop, but that didn't help.

I feel like both of these issues should be fairly straight-forward to address, I'm just not sure how. Any thoughts on how I should modify my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if it will make a difference, but the `XmlTextWriter` constructor docs say `Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, we recommend that you create XmlWriter instances by using the XmlWriter.Create method and the XmlWriterSettings class to take advantage of new functionality.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-ordering the commands a bit. Here is the working code:

```
$randomnumber = Get-Random -minimum 100 -maximum 10000
$xmlFile = "c:\data-$randomnumber.xml"
$xmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter($xmlFile,$Null)
$xmlWriter.Formatting = 'Indented'
$xmlWriter.Indentation = 1
$xmlWriter.IndentChar = "`t"
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('MasterList')

#Get the list of GPOs that start with "wsus".
$wsusGPOs = Get-GPO -All | where {$_.DisplayName -like 'wsus*'} 

Foreach ($gpo in $wsusGPOs) {
#Get the list of AD groups that have the "Apply" permission, in each GPO.
$wsusPerms = $gpo | Get-GPPermission -All | where {$_.permission -eq 'GpoApply' -and $_.denied -eq $false}

    Foreach ($securityGroup in $wsusPerms) {
        If ($securityGroup.trustee.name -ne 'Authenticated Users') {
            #For each AD group that can apply the GPO, get the list of servers in the AD group. Ignores the "Authenticated Users" group. 
            Foreach ($computer in (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $securityGroup.Trustee.name -Recursive).name) {
                $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('Tag')
                $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('TagName',$gpo.DisplayName)
                $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('NodeName',$computer)
                $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() #Closes the "Tag" element
            }
        }
    }
}
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() #Closes the "MasterList" top-level element
$xmlWriter.Flush()
$xmlWriter.Close()
$xmlContent = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($xmlFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a call to WriteEndElement() in the loop:

```
...
Foreach ($permsList in $wsusPerms) {
    If ($permsList.trustee.name -ne 'Authenticated Users') {
        #For each AD group that can apply the GPO, get the list of servers in the AD group. Ignores the "Authenticated Users" group. 
        $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('NodeName',(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $permsList.Trustee.name -Recursive).name)
        $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
    }
}
...
```